# How to change font size on stat_poly_eq in ggplot2 R

Tags: r, ggplot2, fonts, size

I have a ggplot stored in say `p` and wish to add a `poly_stat_eq` layer to display the equation of the curve. I want to change to font size of the text but I'm unable to find a documentation on how to achieve it

```
p + 
  stat_poly_eq(formula = y ~ x, 
               aes(label = paste(..eq.label.., ..rr.label.., sep = "~~~")),
               label.x = 4, label.y = -5, parse = TRUE)
```

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/a/54135578/786542

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just set `size = some real number`. In your case this would look like

```
 p + 
  stat_poly_eq(formula = y ~ x, 
               aes(label = paste(..eq.label.., ..rr.label.., sep = "~~~")),
               label.x = 4, label.y = -5, parse = TRUE, size = 2.4)
```

Just change the number after `size =` to whatever you want. The `ggpmisc` additional examples page is a good place to look over as well. You can find that  [here](https://mran.revolutionanalytics.com/snapshot/2016-03-14/web/packages/ggpmisc/vignettes/examples.html). I hope this helps.